# Search through all document fields (nested and root document) in one multi match query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-nested

Let's assume these basic documents as an example:

```
{
  "name": "pants",
  "description": "with stripes",
  "items": [
    {
      "color": "red",
      "size": "44"
    },
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "size": "38"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "name": "shirt",
  "description": "with stripes",
  "items": [
    {
      "color": "green",
      "size": "40"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "name": "pants",
  "description": "with dots",
  "items": [
    {
      "color": "green",
      "size": "38"
    },
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "size": "38"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to find the first document with a search term like `pants stripes blue 38`. All terms should be connected with AND as I'm not interested in pants with dots or other size and color combinations.

My mapping looks like this:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index.queries.cache.enabled": true,
    "index.number_of_shards": 1,
    "index.number_of_replicas": 2,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "german_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_german_"
        },
        "german_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "light_german"
        },
        "synonym": {
          "type": "synonym_graph",
          "synonyms_path": "dictionaries/de/synonyms.txt",
          "updateable" : true
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "index_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "german_stop",
            "german_normalization",
            "german_stemmer"
          ]
        },
        "search_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "synonym",
            "german_stop",
            "german_normalization",
            "german_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "index_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "index_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
      },
      "items": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "color": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "index_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
          },
          "size": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "index_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please ignore the fact that I'm using german stop words and such. I kept the example files above in english so that everyone can understand it but didn't adjust the mapping as the original example is in german.

So ideally what I want my query to look like is this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "items",
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "pants stripes blue 38",
          "fields": [
            "name",
            "description", 
            "items.color",
            "items.size"
          ],
          "type": "cross_fields",
          "operator": "and", 
          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": "false",
          "fuzzy_transpositions": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the Search Profiler from Kibana show that the query will be executed like this:

```
ToParentBlockJoinQuery (
+(
    +(items.color:pant | items.size:pant | name:pant | description:pant)
    +(items.color:strip | items.size:strip | name:strip | description:strip)
    +(items.color:blu | items.size:blu | name:blu | description:blu)
    +(items.color:38 | items.size:38 | name:38 | description:38)
) #_type:__items)
```

Which looks to be exactly what I need in terms of AND and OR logic. Search through every attribute with every term and connect those results with AND. So every search term needs to be in one of the fields but it doesn't matter in which it was found.

But this query seems to only search inside the nested documents. In fact it seems like each query can only search through nested objects or the root document. Not both at the same time. If I remove the nested part the Search Profiler shows the difference:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "pants stripes blue 38",
      "fields": [
        "name",
        "description",
        "items.color",
        "items.size"
      ],
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "operator": "and",
      "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": "false",
      "fuzzy_transpositions": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

Results in:

```
+(
    +(items.color:pant | items.size:pant | name:pant | description:pant)
    +(items.color:strip | items.size:strip | name:strip | description:strip)
    +(items.color:blu | items.size:blu | name:blu | description:blu)
    +(items.color:38 | items.size:38 | name:38 | description:38)
) #DocValuesFieldExistsQuery [field=_primary_term]
```

Both queries return zero results.

So my question is if there is a way to make the above query work and to be able to truly search across all defined fields (nested and root doc) within a multi match query on a term by term basis.

I would like to avoid doing any preprocessing to the search terms in order to split them up based on them being in a nested or root document as that has it's own set of challenges. But I do know that this is a solution to my problem.

**Edit**
The original files have a lot more attributes. The root document might have up to 250 fields and each nested document might add another 20-30 fields to it. Because the search terms need to search through lot of the fields (possibly not all) any sort of concatenation of nested and root document attributes to make them "searchable" seems unpractical.

A flattened index might be a practical solution. By that I mean copying all root documents fields to the nested document and only indexing the nested docs. But in this question I would like to know if it also works with nested objects without modifying the original structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition regarding flattening is correct but you don't need to copy the root attributes onto the nested fields. You could do the opposite -- through the [`include_in_root` mapping parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-params).

When you update your mapping like so:

```
PUT inventory
{
  "settings": {
      ... 
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      ...
      "items": {
        "type": "nested",
        "include_in_root": true,     <---
        "properties": {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then index some sample docs (at least one of which includes `pants` because your original question contained none):

```
POST inventory/_doc
{"name":"shirt","description":"with stripes","items":[{"color":"red","size":"44"},{"color":"blue","size":"38"}]}

POST inventory/_doc
{"name":"shirt","description":"with stripes","items":[{"color":"green","size":"40"}]}

POST inventory/_doc
{"name":"shirt","description":"with dots","items":[{"color":"green","size":"38"},{"color":"blue","size":"38"}]}

// this one *should* match
POST inventory/_doc
{"name":"pants","description":"with stripes","items":[{"color":"red","size":"44"},{"color":"blue","size":"39"}]}

POST inventory/_doc
{"name":"pants","description":"with stripes","items":[{"color":"red","size":"44"},{"color":"blue","size":"38"}]}
```

You can then use your 2nd query and keep the nested field paths as they are because they're now available in the root, though somewhat confusingly under the same dot-paths:

```
POST inventory/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "pants stripes blue 38",
      "fields": [
        "name",
        "description",
        "items.color",
        "items.size"
      ],
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "operator": "AND",
      "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": "false",
      "fuzzy_transpositions": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

and only the one fully matching document will be returned:

```
{
  "name":"pants",
  "description":"with stripes",
  "items":[
    {
      "color":"red",
      "size":"44"
    },
    {
      "color":"blue",
      "size":"38"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! As far as my understanding of the `include_in_root` parameter goes it adds the nested object as flat fields. So I thought it might merge multiple items together and we would loose which color belongs to which size. But you say this isn't the case? I will try your solution out on Monday. Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-params

Comment: Yes it'll be flattened, meaning if you had `color: red; size: 38` and `color: blue; size: 42`, the system would've still returned this doc b/c the connections bet. size & color will have been lost. So it's not going to be perfect. To be frank, I don't think ES can handle such natural lang understanding queries without a proper parser. The `multi_match` query is a brute forcer that throws a bunch of terms agains a bunch of fields. But it has no way of knowing which field is which. In other words, even documents of the nonsensical form `color: 38; size: blue` would match because of `mult_match`.

Comment: Unfortunately the connection between color & size is really important for us. So `include_in_root` doesn't suit us. But thank you for taking your time!

Comment: No prob. Good luck!